# Set up iCloud Keychain without phone?

Tags: ios, ipad, icloud, keychain

Is it possible to set up iCloud Keychain without a mobile phone? If it is possible then how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your Mac:

1. Open System Preferences > iCloud
2. Check the box next to "Keychain"

On an iPad:

Settings > iCloud > Turn Keychain On

If you don't have any phone that can receive SMS it looks like you will need to call Apple Support to activate iCloud Keychain.

Comment: (oops, didn't notice the ipad tag)

Comment: When I try to set up iCloud Keychain by turning it on it always asks for a mobile phone number. Is there another way to setup the keychain without having to send a SMS to a phone?

Comment: From: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5813 "If you don't have access to any of your other devices that are using iCloud Keychain, you can still set up iCloud Keychain on another device if you have these items:

Your iCloud Security Code
The device that is using the SMS-capable phone number you provided when you first set up iCloud Keychain. A verification code is sent via SMS to this phone number. If you don't have access to this number, contact Apple Support, who can verify your identity so that you can complete setup on your new device."

Comment: It doesn't seem to say anything about the original setup, but it looks like you can contact apple support to get set up without the SMS step.